# Can I change icon for an app and how?

Tags: macos, applications, icon

I have XAMPP on my Mac with El Capitan and the icon is strange and I don't like it. It is not the same one as I am used to, on my other computer running WIndows. How can I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit any icon by right-clicking (control-clicking) the application, choosing `Get Info`, and dragging the replacement icon over the original icon at the top of the window that appears.

You can also copy and paste the image you'd like to use as an icon, [as mentioned in Apple's documentation](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13922?locale=en_US).

This works for files or folders you'd like to change the icon for.

Comment: I tried dragging and dropping over both images in the Get Info popup (there are two images) and it doesn't work. I also tried to copy the png file dn then selecting the existing image in the Get Info popup and pasting. The image stil doesn't change. It seems like it is updated (the date changes and the file size changes), but it doesn't display correctly.

Comment: Works when I go to Preview, do Select All and THEN copy. After that do paste in the get info popup and it is changed. Thanks!

Comment: Copy-pasting from Preview stopped working for me recently. Drag-n-drop onto app icon in `Get Info` still works.

Answer (score 1):

**HyperSwitch**, apparently, uses a different way to get app icon; regular way won't work with it.

With HyperSwitch, you'll have to manually overwrite `/Applications/<the_app>/Resources/<whatever>.icns` with your own file.

Do it only after the app was launched at least once, because replacing a file changes the app's checksum. If it doesn't match the one from app signature, it won't pass macOS' initial security check.